# Replace string in a list using python and save it with different variable

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to replace a string with another string in a list, but failed and I don't know why.

For example, I have a list:

```
predicts = 
[['__label__1'],
 ['__label__0'],
 ['__label__1'],
 ['__label__1'],
 ['__label__0'],
 ['__label__1']]
```

i want to replace **__label__1** with "OK" and **__label__0** with "NOT OK" and save it in different variable using :

```
pred_label = []
for i in predicts:
  if i == '__label__1':
    pred_label.append("OK")
  else:
    pred_label.append("NOT OK")
```

but it failed to replace any of it

Comment: There is both a `predict` and `predicts` variable in your code, choose one or `predicts` is considered as empty in the second part of your code.

Comment: oke my bad, i already edited it

Comment: using list comprehension
`predicts = [["OK"] if item[0] is "__label__1" else ["NOT OKE"] for item in predicts]`

Comment: As @kevin-mayo points out, you have a list of lists, not a list of strings.  Is this a requirement of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **predicts** variable has two dimensions, try:

```
pred_label = []
for i in predicts:
    if i[0] == '__label__1':
        pred_label.append("OK")
    else:
        pred_label.append("NOT OK")
print(pred_label)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary to map the replacement you wish to make:

```
substituteDict = {'__label__1': 'OK', '__label__0': 'NOT OK'}

replaced_list = []
for i in predicts:
    replaced_list.append(substituteDict.get(i[0]))

print(replaced_list)
```